# gcc warnings on R package installations

Tags: c++, r, installation-package

I am trying to install R on a Debian docker container.  I seem to install R successfully (apt-get install -y r-base).  Then I install packages like this:

```
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('lintr', 'tidyr', 'plyr', 
'dplyr','reshape', 'ggplot2'), \
            dependencies=TRUE, \
            repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

However, I get a bunch of gcc "deprecated" and "redefinition" warnings like the following:

```
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/scoped_ptr.hpp:13:0,
             from ../inst/include/dplyr/Result/GroupedHybridCall.h:4,
             from ../inst/include/dplyr/Result/GroupedCallProxy.h:9,
             from slice.cpp:8:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:74:31: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 explicit scoped_ptr( std::auto_ptr<T> p ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT : px( p.release() )
```

I would like to make sure what are the C/C++ correct versions but I really don't know how to proceed.  Is there some information on R's C++ / gcc requirements that I should consider?  I tried to update gcc but I got that I already have the newest version (4:6.3.0-4).

Thank you!

Comment: which R and Debian version are you using?

Comment: Is there a reason you're worried about these warnings? Deprecation warnings are not necessarily a problem for you -- it's just a warning that some feature being used (in your case `auto_ptr`) will not be supported at some point in the (ostensibly) near future, so that the developer can change their code before the feature is eliminated. That means it still works for now (which is why you get a warning rather than an error). Redefinition warnings might point you toward something to worry about, maybe not, but I don't know what warning you saw. Did you get any errors? Did the packages install?

Comment: @Fábio I got Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), build 4.14.48-coreos-r2, and R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe", Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).  I don't know why it is installing 3.3.3 since it is not the most recent.

Comment: @duckmayr I see several redefinitions for strdup.  I agree that deprecation warnings might not be an issue, I am more concerned by the fact that I am getting so much of those that I might eventually miss more important ones. The packages did install, but I am getting installation errors on some dependencies (units, rgeos and sf).  I will dive into those, I guess I am missing some dependencies.

Comment: @user2839382 to install the latest R version you should install it from Debian sid/unstable repository.

Comment: @user2839382 I am experimenting the same issue (having lots of warnings: class std:auto_ptr is deprecated) and I too was missing some errors due to the amount of warnings. I am also trying to install the `sf` package, have you figured out a way to do it ?